# How do I override d3.js chart function behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

There is a popular library in [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) that provides a **bullet chart** implementation. I am in the process of making a small amendment to the default behaviour of this chart.

A *bullet chart* consists of one or more **markers**, *parallel lines to identify targets*, and I wish to programatically make one of the markers slightly shorter in length than the other. I'm pretty close to the solution and I have shared my work at [Bullet Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/finbarleahy/jc7bftsL/28/). To see my issue you have to hit the **Year** and **Quarter** buttons and notice how that the line shrinks and grows and then shrinks again. I want it to remain at the shorter length.

It seems that the default behaviour of the bullet is trigged at each update which is causing it to reset the marker to it's original size. I would love some help to understand how I can override this default behaviour and keep the line at a custom size.

This is a sample of the code that I use to update the marker:

```
 d3.selectAll(".bullet .marker.s1").attr("y1", 10).attr("y2", 35);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code in the library that is causing your changes to be overwritten:

```
  marker.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("x1", x1)
      .attr("x2", x1)
      .attr("y1", height / 6)       // the y1 and y2 values get updated here
      .attr("y2", height * 5 / 6);
```

So the easiest way would just be to fork the library and delete the couple of lines. Otherwise, I didn't see that the marker definitions get exposed as part of the chart for you to remove the transition.

Comment: I just wonder if it's good practice to override a core library? What happens when I take down the latest version of d3.js! It's sure to be overridden. It is possible to extend/override functions with javascript but what's the recommend practice?

Comment: This isn't in the core library, it's in a separate charts library. If you need just the bullet chart, you can just copy over that piece (it's pretty small) and make the changes you need. D3 is all about flexibility to create your own charts, just use the bullet code as a starting point and go wild. If it does what you need, you should never need to pull down a new version.